# Displaying toggle button

Tags: gtk

i am new to gtk and i dont know how to display a toggle button in gtk.
there are no examples of the same for gtk+3.
here is what i did

```
GtkToolItem *tog;

tog = gtk_toggle_tool_button_new();
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(tog), FALSE);
```

i tried to add toggle button to grid, container. i also tried using `gtk_widget_show` and pass `tog` but of no use. 
can any one show me the an example code or how to solve this.

PS: not a C++ programmer.

Comment: What led you to use GtkToolItem and `gtk_toggle_tool_button_new()` instead of GtkToggleButton and `gtk_toggle_button_new()`? Just wondering so we can clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show all your toplevel's widgets:

```
// cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` main.c

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkToolItem *tool;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    tool = gtk_toggle_tool_button_new ();
    gtk_tool_button_set_label (GTK_TOOL_BUTTON (tool), "Hi there");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), GTK_WIDGET (tool), 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```